# Weird syntax error when comparing x with x.method

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Why this works fine:

```
t="
"+$<.read;puts t.reverse==t ?"YES":"NO"
```

but this:

```
t="
"+$<.read;puts t==t.reverse ?"YES":"NO"
```

says:

```
A.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tCHAR, expecting $end
"+$<.read;puts t==t.reverse ?"YES":"NO"
                              ^
```

I use ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32].
Sample STDIN string is `XX.\n...\n.XX\n`.

Comment: How is this code golf?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ruby is parsing the latter as a potential call to `#reverse?`. That ambiguity is removed when switched the other way. Adding parentheses around the conditional should allow it to go both ways.

Comment: +1. This looks like a typical case of not using parenthesis to force the interpreter's understanding of where parameters are. Using `(t == t.reverse)` would have fixed it. I know parenthesis use is optional and a lot of Ruby coders eschew them, but, coming from C and Perl, I prefer to force precedence by putting parenthesis in place.

Comment: Either way works, you just need a space after the ? in the ternary.

Comment: @theTinMan, it's not like if I *just don't like parenthesis*. It's a code from codegolfing.

Comment: Code-golf questions are a special case. They often use coding styles that are going to obfuscate the meaning and/or confuse the interpreter.

Comment: @theTinMan, the question isn't "I wrote this code, why I shouldn't", but is "why does interpreter says this".

Comment: Folks, let's not have an extended argument here. I've answered your question on why the interpreter didn't accept one line of code. The motive is irrelevant here. Let's move on.

Comment: Argument? I see none. I see a discussion why Ruby behaves a certain way.

Comment: Let's just say I'm sick of seeing notifications. Take it to chat.stackoverflow.com :-P